# How can I connect Microsoft PowerApps with Power Point

Tags: powerpoint, powerapps

I want to export data from PowerApps to PowerPoint. Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in PowerApps as you will be needing a connector that can generate these PowerPoint files.

You can however use third party APIs like Aspose Slides or Open XML and use Power Automate Flow to pass your data and retrieve the PowerPoint output.